# Undefined index: usersJSON on line 6 []

Tags: php, android, mysql, arrays, json

I am trying to get JSON posted by Android application, and then decoding JSON into an Array, but getting: Undefined index: usersJSON on line 6 [ ]

```
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"]; // Undefined index
```

php script looks like this:

```
<?php
include_once './db_functions.php';
//Create Object for DB_Functions clas
$db = new DB_Functions(); 
//Get JSON posted by Android Application
$json = $_POST["usersJSON"]; // Undefined index
//Remove Slashes
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()){
$json = stripslashes($json);
}
//Decode JSON into an Array
$data = json_decode($json);
//Util arrays to create response JSON
$a=array();
$b=array();
//Loop through an Array and insert data read from JSON into MySQL DB
for($i=0; $i<count($data) ; $i++)
{
//Store User into MySQL DB
$res = $db->storeUser($data[$i]->userId,$data[$i]->userName);
    //Based on inserttion, create JSON response
    if($res){
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'yes';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }else{
        $b["id"] = $data[$i]->userId;
        $b["status"] = 'no';
        array_push($a,$b);
    }
}
//Post JSON response back to Android Application
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: Undefined index means ur not having the value for that index

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `$_POST["usersJSON"]` is not set or empty(you haven't value for this index)

check you are posting on url like

```
usersJSON='yourjsondata'
```

For hide undefined index error you need to check first by `isset()` or `empty()`

```
$json = (isset($_POST["usersJSON"])? $_POST["usersJSON"] : '');
```

or check for empty

```
if(!empty($_POST["usersJSON"]) {
   $json = $_POST["usersJSON"];
 }
 else {
  echo 'getting blank'; 
 }
```

Comment: now i am getting [ ] at this line: $data = json_decode($json); Undefined variable: json

Comment: you are not getting post data can you please post your code how you posting data

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your application is posting to a different name or not posting at all (Did you do a post or a get?)

You could try dumping all $_POST with var_dump($_POST) so you can figure out what the application is posting as (if any). If this array is empty, that means it's not sending as "POST". You could check the $_GET array... If that's the case you probably need to fix the Android application to send correctly post requests :)